# Standalone SVN Viewer

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm currently using tortoiseSVN to version control my localy programmed files. I don't run an SVN Server since one can use tortoiseSVN directly (look e.g. http://invalidlogic.com/2006/12/06/using-subversion-without-a-subversion-server/), as I don't like the heck about installing the SVN server. Now I have my repository and my real programming files and I'm looking for a standalone application (which I download, install and open) to point to my repository and see a nice version history; just like what the webbased SVN viewers offer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RapidSVN has worked for me:
http://www.rapidsvn.org/

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN with it's Repository Browser?!

Just use "file:///" protocol for accessing local repo

Answer (score 0):

I like [Sventon](http://sventon.org). It's open source and powerful, but you have to run it inside a Tomcat instance, and must have Java 1.6 Runtime installed.

I use `svnserve` as my private Subversion server. Svnserve comes with Subversion, and is quick and easy to install. The advantage is that I can share my repository if needed. Plus, the URLs are shorter:

```
C:> svn checkout "file:///C:/Documents and Settings/dweintraub/svn_repos/trunk"
```

vs.

```
C:> svn checkout svn://localhost/trunk
```

Comment: fyi: the link is dead.